# problems getting curl / json work with php

Tags: php, mysql, json, curl

I just wanted to ask one of my servers (let's call him mysql-server) a simple question to get some result out of a MySQL database.

This mysql-server provides the result as json decoded array in the form - e.g. like this:

```
$data = array("first_name" => "First name","last_name" => "last name");
$data_string = json_encode(array("customer" => $data));
echo $data_string;
```

which works pretty well and returns something like this:

```
{"customer":{"first_name":"First name","last_name":"last name"}}
```

Just to check that everything is fine I added a few lines:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($data_string, true))."</pre>";
```

and got the following:

```
Array(
[customer] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => First name
        [last_name] => last name
    )
```

)

So everything seems to be fine on this server side.

If I now call the url of that script from the second-server using:

```
$data_string =  json_encode(array('customer' => $customerNo));
$curlHandler = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($curlHandler, [
CURLOPT_URL => $url, 
CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
CURLOPT_STDERR => fopen($fp, 'w'),
//CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST == 2,
//CURLOPT_VERIFYPEER == true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Accept: application/json',
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
]);
$response = curl_exec($curlHandler);  
var_dump(json_decode($response, true));
```

I got NULL.

Instead of using

```
echo $response;
```

brings the following result to the screen:

```
{"customer":{"first_name":"First name","last_name":"last name"}}
```

and a

```
var_dump($response);
```

brings the following to the screen:

```
string(268) " {"customer":{"first_name":"First name","last_name":"last name"}} "
```

So the data is transfered back and stored in the variable $response as it should be, but may anyone give me please a hint, why I can't access it using json_decode?

Many thanks and best
Paul

Comment: That string is not supposed to be 268 characters, it's around 79. There are some invisible characters in there breaking the json.

Comment: THANK YOU so much! 

I got it. There were really some hidden html comments... 

No it is working. Live can be so easy :-) 

string(66) "{"customer":{"first_name":"First name","last_name":"last name"}} "
array(1) { ["customer"]=> array(2) { ["first_name"]=> string(10) "First name" ["last_name"]=> string(9) "last name" } }